# Sabre Reference Documentation

Tags: reference, response, documentation, sabre

I am getting familiar with Sabre REST API.  I am trying to understand the response.

Please check this sample:

```
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS": {
    "PricedItinCount": 48,
    "BrandedOneWayItinCount": 0,
    "SimpleOneWayItinCount": 0,
    "DepartedItinCount": 0,
    "SoldOutItinCount": 0,
    "AvailableItinCount": 0,
    "Version": "4.1.0",
    "Success": {},
    "Warnings": {},
    "PricedItineraries": {
      "PricedItinerary": [
        {
          "SequenceNumber": 1,
          "AirItinerary": {
            "DirectionInd": "Return",
            "OriginDestinationOptions": {
              "OriginDestinationOption": [
                {
                  "ElapsedTime": 201,
                  "FlightSegment": []
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone please share a link where to find a documentation where  each element in the response is explained?

For example  in the element "DirectionInd": "Return".

- What "DirectionInd" means?
- What "Return"  means?

I tried to look in the developer.sabre.com portal but I was not able to find any documentation where the DirectionInd is described or explained. It is only shown in the sample response.

Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can find descriptions under this link](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/bfm/v420/OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS_Description.html)

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. It is really useful. 

What the Return means?  I suppose it is a round trip, correct?

Is there a documentation where I can check the possible responses values for DirectionInd ?

I really appreciate your help. 

Thanks